# ui error for setting a scrollView in stackView iOS

Tags: ios, swift

[image: IB error]

Hi programmers actually I stuck in UI and when I want to set scrollView in stack view I have an error like this photo, do you know what the problem is?

In below , I bring the constraints

[image: IB constraints]

Actually I want to fit this ui to every screen sizes and I try a lot to set comfortable constraints to scrollView on stackView but I don't know what do I do? thank you for your attention

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have missing or incorrectly set constraints somewhere, but we need to see the constraints you have setup. Please review [ask].

Comment: good job every one , sorry for structure of my question because website have  error for put a photo but I put the link of photo in question

Comment: Looks like you are missing constraints for: scrollView size, imageView size, and imageView-to-scrollView Content Layout Guide

Comment: thanks for answer , now what's your opinion ? how could I solve it? or do know a good education that I can learn it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know your problem, just ignore the error before you correctly add a content view in your scrollView everytime, you can't set an imageview as the content view, pls notice that before you set correct constraints, the error will always persist.

Follow this tutorial to implement your scrollview:
https://fluffy.es/scrollview-storyboard-xcode-11/

Comment: yeah thanks a lot for you and other people help me to share and edit and solve my question I drag content layout guid and frame layout guid to my image and advance equal width and height , and errors went away, again thanks, good job